# MathJax doesn't render open symbols in react

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mathjax, mathml

I am currently working with formulas in **MathML** (it is a requirement, the data comes this way from the backend, I cant edit the database):

[image]

I am using **MathJax in react** with **better-react-mathjax** for render the formula and when trying to use the render does not show opening tags when using the mfenced tag with its property **open='{'** (the mfenced properity is automatic generate in python):

[image]

Looking in the documentation I found that mfenced is a deprecated tag, but in the MathJax documentation it is mentioned that it has support for MathLm, the same thing happens in the better-react-mathjax documentation; any idea or solution? Thank you!

versions:
"react": "^17.0.2"
"better-react-mathjax": "^2.0.1"

Comment: I have posted an answer to this question here: https://github.com/fast-reflexes/better-react-mathjax/issues/23. the problem lies in React which for some reason treats the `open` attribute like a boolean no matter the value (e.g. any non-falsish value results in `open=true` which is abbreviated to `open` only in the DOM which MathJax interprets as "there should be no opening symbol").